# WCAG 2.0 validation - "Consecutive text and image links to the same resource"

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3, wcag, wcag2.0

I am using [tawdis](http://www.tawdis.net/index.html?lang=es) online tool to validate WCAG 2.0 AA Level compatibility. I am facing an error "`Consecutive text and image links to the same resource`", when I use below code. How to fix this error in WCAG validation ?

```
<ul>
    <li><div><a href="#"><em class="fa fa-instagram" title="instagram"></em></a></div></li>
    <li><div><a href="#"><em class="fa fa-facebook-square" title="facebook"></em></a></div></li>
    <li><div><a href="#"><em class="fa fa-pinterest-square" title="pinterest"></em></a></div></li>
    <li><div><a href="#"><em class="fa fa-youtube-square" title="youtube"></em></a></div></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: 1. Are you aware that your links are not accessible because they are empty? 2. It doesn’t seem to be appropriate to use the `em` element here. Should probably be `span`. 3. Did you test exactly this markup (i.e., with `#` as `href` value for all links)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This refers to the [H2: Combining adjacent image and text links for the same resource](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H2.html) technique of the WCAG.

As I suppose you have posted your full code, I guess that you use some sort of javascript for those links. And so the Tawdis parser thinks that those links target the same URI.

In reality, **this is a bad analyze from that parser** as it should have noted that the anchor `#` is often used to mark a javascript link (although it's not a valid URI and a bad practice).

You have different things to do:

- use a meaningful tag for what appears to be a `button`, not a link,
- do not use a tag like `em` which has a semantic meaning,
- provide a text alternative.

Example:

```
 <ul>
    <li><button class="fa fa-instagram">Instagram</button></li>
    <li><button class="fa fa-facebook-square">Facebook</button></li>
    <li><button class="fa fa-pinterest-square">Pinterest</button></li>
    <li><button class="fa fa-youtube-square">Youtube</button></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
   <ul>
        <li><div><a href="#"><em class="fa fa-instagram" title="instagram" alt="instagram"></em></a></div></li>
        <li><div><a href="#"><em class="fa fa-facebook-square" title="face" alt="face"></em></a></div></li>
        <li><div><a href="#"><em class="fa fa-pinterest-square" title="pinta" alt="pinta"></em></a></div></li>
        <li><div><a href="#"><em class="fa fa-youtube-square" title="youtube" alt="youtube"></em></a></div></li>
    </ul>
```

[Techniques/HTML/Combining adjacent image and text links for the same resource](https://www.w3.org/WAI/GL/wiki/Techniques/HTML/Combining_adjacent_image_and_text_links_for_the_same_resource)

Comment: An `alt` attribute is of no use for an `em` tag